# How Can I put all my If statement in only one class or function?

Tags: java, android

I have a lot of if statements in my code, is it possible to create a function or list and include all of them into it?

I want to summarize those ifs to reduce the length of my code so I can change it easily afterward. It's difficult to go inside every if to change it. It would be easier to have one big function with all of those ifs and then I can manipulate them in case of adding new events.
Can somebody help me please?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String ERROR_DETECTED = "No NFC tag detected!";
    public static final String WRITE_SUCCESS = "Text written to the NFC tag successfully!";
    public static final String WRITE_ERROR = "Error during writing, is the NFC tag close enough to your device?";
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    IntentFilter writeTagFilters[];
    boolean writeMode;
    Tag myTag;
    Context context;

    Button btnWrite;
    View D1,D2,D3,D4,Autoprotection,Etat_centrale,Capot,Alimentation,PP4;
    TextView tvNFCContent,message, nfc_annoce, CompteurTelecommandes,Conseil_detecteur,text_centrale,Telecommande_centrale,Titre_systeme,Titre_telecommande,Nbre_defauts4,Defauts_capot,Defauts_pion;
    ImageView back,Batterie;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main );
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        context = this;

        tvNFCContent =  findViewById(R.id.contenu);
        message = findViewById(R.id.ecriture);
        PP4 =findViewById(R.id.pp4);
        btnWrite = findViewById(R.id.ecrire_nfc);

        Etat_centrale = findViewById(R.id.etat_final);
        D1 = findViewById(R.id.detecteur_1);
        D2 = findViewById(R.id.detecteur_2);
        D3 = findViewById(R.id.detecteur_3);
        D4 = findViewById(R.id.detecteur_4);
        Alimentation = findViewById(R.id.alimentation);
        Autoprotection = findViewById(R.id.tamper);
        Capot = findViewById(R.id.capot);
        Batterie = findViewById(R.id.batterie);
        Telecommande_centrale= findViewById(R.id.telecommande_inconnu);
        Defauts_capot=findViewById(R.id.defaut_capot);
        Defauts_pion=findViewById(R.id.defaut_tamper);
        CompteurTelecommandes=findViewById(R.id.compteur_télecommande);
        Conseil_detecteur=findViewById(R.id.conseil);
        text_centrale=findViewById(R.id.centrale_text);
        Titre_systeme=findViewById(R.id.titre_systeme);
        Titre_telecommande=findViewById(R.id.titre_telecommande);


        // Mode_alimentation = findViewById(R.id.mode_alim);
        //Telecommande_arret = findViewById(R.id.telecommande_arret);
        //Telecommande_trame= findViewById(R.id.telecommande_trame);
        //Telecommande_centrale= findViewById(R.id.telecommande_centrale);
        //Nbre_defauts1= findViewById(R.id.nbre_defauts1);
        //Nbre_defauts2= findViewById(R.id.nbre_defauts2);
        //Nbre_defauts3= findViewById(R.id.nbre_defauts3);
        //Nbre_defauts4= findViewById(R.id.nbre_defauts4);

        PP4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        nfc_annoce = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        nfc_annoce.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        back=findViewById(R.id.Reader);
        back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        CompteurTelecommandes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Conseil_detecteur.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        text_centrale.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Titre_telecommande.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Titre_systeme.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        D1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View a) {
                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,-150);
                TextView tv = new TextView (MainActivity.this) ;
                tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blanc);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tv.setTextSize(15);
                tv.setText("Détecteur 1"
                );
                Typeface t = Typeface.create( "serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
                tv.setTypeface(t);
                tv.setPadding(50, 50,50,50);
                toast.setView(tv);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
        D2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View b) {

                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,-150);
                TextView tv = new TextView (MainActivity.this) ;
                tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blanc);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tv.setTextSize(15);
                tv.setText("Détecteur 2");
                Typeface t = Typeface.create( "serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
                tv.setTypeface(t);
                tv.setPadding(50, 50,50,50);
                toast.setView(tv);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
        D3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View c) {
                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,-150);
                TextView tv = new TextView (MainActivity.this) ;
                tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blanc);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tv.setTextSize(15);
                tv.setText("Détecteur 3"
                );
                Typeface t = Typeface.create( "serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
                tv.setTypeface(t);
                tv.setPadding(50, 50,50,50);
                toast.setView(tv);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
        D4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View d) {
                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,-150);
                TextView tv = new TextView (MainActivity.this) ;
                tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blanc);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tv.setTextSize(15);
                tv.setText("Détecteur 4");
                Typeface t = Typeface.create( "serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
                tv.setTypeface(t);
                tv.setPadding(50, 50,50,50);
                toast.setView(tv);
                toast.show();
            }
        });


        btnWrite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    if(myTag ==null) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, ERROR_DETECTED, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        write(message.getText().toString(), myTag);
                        Toast.makeText(context, WRITE_SUCCESS, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, WRITE_ERROR, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FormatException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, WRITE_ERROR, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (nfcAdapter == null) {
            // Stop here, we definitely need NFC
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cet appareil ne possède pas la technologie NFC", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        readFromIntent(getIntent());

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
        tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };
    }


    /******************************************************************************
     **********************************Read From NFC Tag***************************
     ******************************************************************************/
    private void readFromIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                }
            }
            buildTagViews(msgs);
        }
    }
    private void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
        if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) return;

        String text = "";
//        String tagId = new String(msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getType());
        byte[] payload = msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
        String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16"; // Get the Text Encoding
        int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063; // Get the Language Code, e.g. "en"
        // String languageCode = new String(payload, 1, languageCodeLength, "US-ASCII");

        try {
            // Get the Text

            text = new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", e.toString());
        }


        tvNFCContent.setText(text+"(( taille de la trame: " + text.length () +"))");
        //lenght.setText(text.length ());
        //tramemail.setText(text+"(( taille de la trame: " + text.length () +"))" + Version);
        nfc_annoce.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        back.setVisibility(View.GONE);



        //Nbre_defauts1.setText("  Le Nombre de défauts enregistrés sur le détecteur 1 est de "+ text.charAt(39)+ text.charAt(40));
        //Nbre_defauts2.setText("  Le Nombre de défauts enregistrés sur le détecteur 2 est de "+ text.charAt(41)+ text.charAt(42));
        //Nbre_defauts3.setText("  Le Nombre de défauts enregistrés sur le détecteur 3 est de "+ text.charAt(43)+ text.charAt(44));
        //Nbre_defauts4.setText("  Le Nombre de défauts enregistrés sur le détecteur 4 est de "+ text.charAt(45)+ text.charAt(46));
        //Nbre_defauts_pion.setText("  Le Nombre de défauts enregistrés sur l'autoprotection est de "+ text.charAt(57)+ text.charAt(58));
        //Nbre_defauts_capot.setText("  Le Nombre de défauts enregistrés sur le capot est de "+ text.charAt(55)+ text.charAt(56));

        CompteurTelecommandes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Conseil_detecteur.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        PP4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        text_centrale.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Titre_systeme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Titre_telecommande.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (text.charAt(6) == 'O')
        {
            Etat_centrale.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_ok);
        } else
        {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Centrale en Alarme");
            alertDialog.setMessage(" La centrale de sécurisation est en défaut.\n" +
                    "Une intervention de votre part est nécessaire !");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Fermer",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
            Etat_centrale.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_warning_red);
        }




        if (text.charAt(7) == 'A') {
            D1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_warning_red);
        } else if (text.charAt(7) == 'O') {
            D1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_ok);
        } else if (text.charAt(7) == 'W') {
            D1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic__warning_orange);
        } else {
            D1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_block_24);
        }
        if (text.charAt(8) == 'A') {
            D2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_warning_red);
        } else if (text.charAt(8) == 'O') {
            D2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_ok);
        } else if (text.charAt(8) == 'W') {
            D2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic__warning_orange);
        } else {
            D2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_block_24);
        }

        if (text.charAt(9) == 'A') {
            D3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_warning_red);
        } else if (text.charAt(9) == 'O') {
            D3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_ok);
        } else if (text.charAt(9) == 'W') {
            D3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic__warning_orange);
        } else {
            D3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_block_24);
        }

        if (text.charAt(10) == 'A') {
            D4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_warning_red);
        } else if (text.charAt(10) == 'O') {
            D4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_ok);
        } else if (text.charAt(10) == 'W') {
            D4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic__warning_orange);
        } else {
            D4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_block_24);
        }



        if (text.charAt(59)== 'O'){
            Capot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Autoprotection capot enclenchée", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Capot.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.capot_vert);
            Defauts_capot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        else {
            Capot.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.capot_rouge);
            Capot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,-150);
                    TextView tv = new TextView (MainActivity.this) ;
                    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blanc);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tv.setTextSize(15);
                    tv.setText("Défaut autoprotection capot \n" +
                            "Vérifiez que le capot est bien fermé et vissé");
                    Typeface t = Typeface.create( "serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
                    tv.setTypeface(t);
                    tv.setPadding(50, 50,50,50);
                    toast.setView(tv);
                    toast.show();

                }
            });


            Defauts_capot.setText("Défaut autoprotection capot \n"+
                    "Vérifiez que le capot est bien fermé et vissé");
        }



        if (text.charAt(60) == 'O') {
            Autoprotection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View e) {
                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,-150);
                    TextView tv = new TextView (MainActivity.this) ;
                    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blanc);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tv.setTextSize(15);
                    tv.setText("Autoprotection base enclenchée");
                    Typeface t = Typeface.create( "serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
                    tv.setTypeface(t);
                    tv.setPadding(50, 50,50,50);
                    toast.setView(tv);
                    toast.show();

                }
            });
            Autoprotection.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pion_vert);
            Defauts_pion.setVisibility(View.GONE); }

        else  {
            Autoprotection.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pion_rouge);
            Autoprotection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View e) {
                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,-150);
                    TextView tv = new TextView (MainActivity.this) ;
                    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blanc);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tv.setTextSize(15);
                    tv.setText("Défaut autoprotection base \n" +
                            "Vérifiez le contact et la fixation de la centrale du mobilier.\n" +
                            "Selon l'installation, revissez ou re-adhésivez la centrale");
                    Typeface t = Typeface.create( "serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
                    tv.setTypeface(t);
                    tv.setPadding(50, 50,50,50);
                    toast.setView(tv);
                    toast.show();

                }
            });
            Defauts_pion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Defauts_pion.setText("Défaut autoprotection base\n " +
                    "Vérifiez le contact et la fixation de la centrale au mobilier \n" +
                    "Selon l'installation, revissez ou re-adhésivez la centrale");
        }


        if (text.charAt(61) == 'P') {
            Alimentation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_power_vert);
            Alimentation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,-150);
                    TextView tv = new TextView (MainActivity.this) ;
                    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blanc);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tv.setTextSize(15);
                    tv.setText("Alimentation secteur");
                    Typeface t = Typeface.create( "serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
                    tv.setTypeface(t);
                    tv.setPadding(50, 50,50,50);
                    toast.setView(tv);
                    toast.show();

                }
            });

        }
        else if (text.charAt(61)== 'B') {
            Alimentation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_power_bleu);
            Alimentation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,-150);
                    TextView tv = new TextView (MainActivity.this) ;
                    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blanc);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tv.setTextSize(15);
                    tv.setText("Alimentation double secteur");
                    Typeface t = Typeface.create( "serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
                    tv.setTypeface(t);
                    tv.setPadding(50, 50,50,50);
                    toast.setView(tv);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            Alimentation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,-150);
                    TextView tv = new TextView (MainActivity.this) ;
                    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blanc);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tv.setTextSize(15);
                    tv.setText("Alimentation pile");
                    Typeface t = Typeface.create( "serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
                    tv.setTypeface(t);
                    tv.setPadding(50, 50,50,50);
                    toast.setView(tv);
                    toast.show();

                }
            });
            Alimentation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_power_rouge);

        }
        if (text.charAt(62) == 'H') {
            Batterie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,-150);
                    TextView tv = new TextView (MainActivity.this) ;
                    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blanc);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tv.setTextSize(15);
                    tv.setText("Capacité de la pile (CR 123 A) optimale");
                    Typeface t = Typeface.create( "serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
                    tv.setTypeface(t);
                    tv.setPadding(50, 50,50,50);
                    toast.setView(tv);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });
            Batterie.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.batterie_full); }
        else if (text.charAt(62)== 'M'){
            Batterie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,-150);
                    TextView tv = new TextView (MainActivity.this) ;
                    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blanc);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tv.setTextSize(15);
                    tv.setText("Pile (CR 123 A) à 50% de sa capacité");
                    Typeface t = Typeface.create( "serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
                    tv.setTypeface(t);
                    tv.setPadding(50, 50,50,50);
                    toast.setView(tv);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });
            Batterie.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.batterie_midlle);
        }
        else if (text.charAt(62)== 'L'){
            Batterie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,-150);
                    TextView tv = new TextView (MainActivity.this) ;
                    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blanc);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tv.setTextSize(15);
                    tv.setText("Capacité de la pile (CR 123 A) faible \n" +
                            "\n"+
                            "Vite, remplacez-la ! "
                    );
                    Typeface t = Typeface.create( "serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
                    tv.setTypeface(t);
                    tv.setPadding(50, 50,50,50);
                    toast.setView(tv);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });
            Batterie.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.batterie_vide);
        }
        else {
            Batterie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,-150);
                    TextView tv = new TextView (MainActivity.this) ;
                    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blanc);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tv.setTextSize(15);
                    tv.setText("Aucune pile insérée." +
                            "Pour une installation 100% sécurisée, nous vous conseillons d'insérer une pile CR 123 A"
                    );
                    Typeface t = Typeface.create( "serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
                    tv.setTypeface(t);
                    tv.setPadding(50, 50,50,50);
                    toast.setView(tv);
                    toast.show();

                }
            });
            Batterie.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.batterie_absente);
        }


        //int version = (int)text.charAt(4);
        if (text.charAt(67)=='I'|| text.charAt(72)=='I') {
            Telecommande_centrale.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Telecommande_centrale.setText("Attention:des télécommandes inconnues ont été présentées à la centrale" +
                    "Consultez la procédure d'affection des télécommandes");
        }
        else{
            Telecommande_centrale.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_share:
                Intent sharingIntent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody= "Bonjour";
                String shareSubject= "Retour SAV";

                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,shareBody);
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,shareSubject);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "partager avec"));
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /******************************************************************************
     **********************************Write to NFC Tag****************************
     ******************************************************************************/
    private void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {
        NdefRecord[] records = { createRecord(text) };
        NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(records);
        // Get an instance of Ndef for the tag.
        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        // Enable I/O
        ndef.connect();
        // Write the message
        ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
        // Close the connection
        ndef.close();
    }
    private NdefRecord createRecord(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String lang       = "en";
        byte[] textBytes  = text.getBytes();
        byte[] langBytes  = lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
        int    langLength = langBytes.length;
        int    textLength = textBytes.length;
        byte[] payload    = new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];

        // set status byte (see NDEF spec for actual bits)
        payload[0] = (byte) langLength;

        // copy langbytes and textbytes into payload
        System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1,              langLength);
        System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payload, 1 + langLength, textLength);

        NdefRecord recordNFC = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,  NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT,  new byte[0], payload);

        return recordNFC;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        readFromIntent(intent);
        if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            myTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        WriteModeOff();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        WriteModeOn();
    }



    /******************************************************************************
     **********************************Enable Write********************************
     ******************************************************************************/
    private void WriteModeOn(){
        writeMode = true;
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, writeTagFilters, null);
    }
    /******************************************************************************
     **********************************Disable Write*******************************
     ******************************************************************************/
    private void WriteModeOff(){
        writeMode = false;
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }


}
```

Comment: I wouldn't concentrate on collecting your `if` statements together.  Rather, I'd concentrate on reducing the number of them..."summarize those ifs" as you say.  There are many places in your code where you repeat code blocks that do the same thing, but on a different variable or set of variables.  You should learn how to refactor those into a single function that takes parameters to define what is different in each case you are combining together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to reduce the length of my code so I can change it easily after
> because it's difficult to go onside every if to change it

As @Steve proposed, you could refactor the code to make it smaller and easier to mofity/edit. One possible way is to say, create a method updateTextview(). Something like

```
private void updateTextview(final String text){
  Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
  toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,-150);
  TextView tv = new TextView (MainActivity.this) ;
  tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blanc);
  tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
  tv.setTextSize(15);
  tv.setText(text);
  Typeface t = Typeface.create( "serif", Typeface.NORMAL);
  tv.setTypeface(t);
  tv.setPadding(50, 50,50,50);
  toast.setView(tv);
  toast.show();
}
```

PS: I noticed only the `tv.setText()` was changing. You can add more parameters to the function depending on what changes in the function.

To make use of the method, when adding a listener say on D1, you could have something like

```
D1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View a) {
    final String text = "Détecteur 1";
    updateTextview(text);
  }
});
```

Also, using [switch statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) (as opposed to ifs) could make your code look cleaner.
As an example, I will take a small piece of if-else-ifs from the code. The ifs on text.charAt(7) changing the BackgroundResource of D1.

```
char charAt7 = text.charAt(7);
switch(charAt7){
  case 'A' : D1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_warning_red); break;
  case 'O' : D1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_ok); break;
  case 'W' : D1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic__warning_orange); break;
  default: D1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_block_24);
}
```

Comment: can you complete the code with one exemple of toast situation It would really help me

Comment: Can you plz show one exemple using switch statements in place of my ifs because I dont  know how to do it by my self.

Comment: thank you it does work, I have another question: do you know how can I stop nfc reading mode when the tag is empty because now when I read an empty tag my app crash

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Map holding the values, so you can access them directly.
for example:

```java
final Map<Char, Integer> foo = new HashMap();
foo.add('A', R.drawable.ic_warning_red);
foo.add('O', R.drawable.ic_ok);
//... so on
```

Then you could apply it straighfoward

```java
D3.setBackgroundResource(
Optional.ofNullable(foo.get(text.charAt(9)))
   .orElse(R.drawable.ic_baseline_block_24));
```